# Error from using SpatialPolygonDataFrame in a reactive function in shiny.

Tags: shiny, leaflet, rgdal

I've been getting the error

```
Error in states() <- reactive({ : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

when I create reactive functions that return objects with class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in shiny. I've made an example that shows that;

I can subset in leaflet alone and it works. And,

I can put the whole object in a leaflet map in shiny.

But if you put it in a reactive function it will give the error.  How do I subset these spatial objects in shiny to pass to leaflet in shiny?

```
library(leaflet)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(shiny)

# From https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html
# Get the 20m file, unzip and put in your working directory.
states <- readOGR("cb_2014_us_state_20m.shp",
                  layer = "cb_2014_us_state_20m", verbose = FALSE)

neStates <- subset(states, states$STUSPS %in% c(
  "CT","ME","MA","NH","RI","VT","NY","NJ","PA"
))

leaflet(neStates) %>%
  addPolygons(
    stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    color = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", states$AWATER)(AWATER)
  )

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(class = "panel panel-default", 
                top = 1, right = 1, width = 300,
  selectInput("which_state","which state", 
              c("CT","ME","MA","NH","RI","VT","NY","NJ","PA"))
)))

#input <- list(which_state = "CT")
server <- function(input, output) {
  states() <- reactive({
    subset(neStates,neStates$STUSPS == input$which_state)
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
    addPolygons(states())
    #addPolygons(data = neStates)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

`anything() <- 2` is not valid syntax, hence the error. You cannot assign something to what looks like a function call (with no parameters).

You probably want `states` rather than `states()` in both places.